# Intel graphics error with Minecraft 1.7.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, graphics-card, windows-8

I have Minecraft 1.7.2 but it wants me to update my Intel Express Four Chipset Family drivers but Intel's site is saying I can't do it on Windows 8 I used the "Intel Auto Checker" for it. Mojang says I need to update my drivers for Minecraft 1.7.2. So the driver I currently have installed is not compatible.

[image: system information]

Comment: Are you saying Minecraft was working before the 1.7.2 update?

Comment: yes before i instaled windows 8

Comment: Is there a reason you're not upgrading to windows 8.1?

Comment: Windows 8 has very poor driver support right now. Minecraft may *need* a newer driver that simply doesn't *exist* yet for Windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [Royal BNA Driver](http://teknogods.com:8081/phpbb/viewforum.php?f=47)? I'm using it on Windows 7 with the same graphics chip that you use, and seems to work much better than the Intel drivers (at least for Minecraft). I've not yet tried it on Windows 8, but later versions of the driver claim to support Windows 8.

[image]